# Declaring a reference to a namespace at runtime in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a c++ program in which I:

1. Have a class which contains, as members, function handles, say `void (*foo)` and `void (*bar)`
2. Have a collection of namespaces, each defining functions of the same name, e.g.:

   - `namespace1` contains functions `void foo()` and `void bar()`
   - `namespace2` also contains functions `void foo()` and `void bar()`

At run-time, I would like the user to be able to pass a variable, say `choice`, which indicates the chosen namespace. The functions in the class would then be mapped to the corresponding functions in the appropriate namespace.

Currently, I'm using something along the following lines:

```
 if (choice == "namespace1") {
     my_class.foo = &(namespace1::foo);
     my_class.bar = &(namespace1::bar);
 } else if (choice == "namespace2") {
     my_class.foo = &(namespace2::foo);
     my_class.bar = &(namespace2::bar);
 }
```

This works well, but becomes rather cumbersome when my list of available namespaces increases and given that each namespace provides 9 functions that I would like to pass into the class.

Are there ways that I can tidy this up? My first thought was something like:

```
 if (choice == "namespace1") {
     my_namespace = namespace1;
 } else if (choice == "namespace2") {
     my_namespace = namespace2;
 }
 my_class.foo = &(my_namespace::foo);
 my_class.bar = &(my_namespace::bar);
```

But, if I understand correctly, I cannot use namespaces as variables.

Is there a better way to formulate this? As structured, is this poor style and, is there a more standard way to go about this?

Thank you for any insights that you might have!

Comment: A better way is not to use multiple  namespaces like this.

Comment: A `namespace` exists only at compile time. There is no `namespace` object generated which is referencable at run-time. Instead, you could define your functions as virtual methods of a (base) class. Every, derived class could provide it's own implementation (via overloading). Instancing each derived class, the whole bundle of (now virtual) functions become addressable by one class pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be aware of the phases of compilation, at least approximately. Names simply do not exist at runtime. Your existing code works by creating pointers for each and every name within each namespace.

The standard solution is to define an *interface*.

```
class IFooBar {
   virtual void foo() = 0;
   virtual void bar() = 0;
   // Other 7 functions.
};
```

This allows each namespace to define one class instead of 9 functions.

Chances are that the compiler behind the scenes creates a "vtable", an array of function pointers, to implement this interface. This would be approximately the same as you do now, but then automated and without the chance of copy-paste errors.

Comment: This adds nicely to what I tried to describe in my above comment.

Comment: well translated sir!  Took me a couple of reads to understand that this is what OP is aiming for

Comment: Thank you! I need to look up interfaces a bit more, but I have a good starting point now!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using traits.

```
template<Context C>
struct context;

template<NAMESPACE_1> struct context<> {
  static foo_return_t foo(...) {
    return namespace1::foo (...);
  }
  static bar_return_t bar(...) {
    return namespace1::bar (...);
  }
};

template<NAMESPACE_2> struct context<> {
  static foo_return_t foo(...) {
    return namespace2::foo (...);
  }
  static bar_return_t bar(...) {
    return namespace2::bar (...);
  }
};
```

Then use like so:

```
foo_ret_t a;
bar_ret_t b; 

if (choice == "namespace1") {
  a = context<NAMESPACE_1>::foo(...);
  b = context<NAMESPACE_1>::bar(...);
} else if (choice == "namespace1") {
  a = context<NAMESPACE_2>::foo(...);
  b = context<NAMESPACE_2>::bar(...);
}
```

Your problem is that the stuff is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Shouldn't those be static functions? You should also show the `NAMESPACE_1` etc. declarations, that part is likely confusing to someone new to the traits concept.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the [the answer by @MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333963/434551) ...

There is a design pattern that addresses this situation. It is called the [Dependency Injection Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Your class (where you are trying to store `foo` and `bar`) is the client.

The namespaces contain classes that implement the interface.

A dependency injector will need to inject the dependency (a pointer to one of the concrete classes in the namespaces) into the client.